# How to generate protobuf Enum as String using ScalaPB?

Tags: protocol-buffers, scalapb

I have the following in my Protobuf message:

```
enum SegmentType {
     UNKNOWN = 0;
     TYPE_1 = 1;
     TYPE_2 = 2;
     TYPE_3 = 3;
        }
optional SegmentType segment_type = 1 [default = UNKNOWN]
```

Instead of `GeneratedEnum` type, I would like to generate a string, with value as the particular type. For example

```
SegmentType: String = "TYPE_1"
```

This [link](https://scalapb.github.io/customizations.html#custom-types) explains how to map as a custom type, but it's not clear to me how to map as a value type. When I try the following, ScalaPB is showing error that it should be implemented in String companion class.

```
implicit val segmentType = TypeMapper[SegmentType, String](_.name)(SegmentType.fromName(_).get)
```

How can I achieve it? Also is there a way to transform all `Enum` types in a message as `String` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the implicit typemapper picked up by the compiler, you can put it in a package object for the same package `SegmentType` belongs to.

Let's say your proto has a package statement like this:

```
package a.b.c.d;
```

Then in Scala:

```
package a.b.c

package object d {
  implicit val segmentType =
    TypeMapper[SegmentType, String](_.name)(SegmentType.fromName(_).get)
}
```

You can also have it in any parent package of `a.b.c.d` (such as `a.b.c`, `a.b` or `a`).

To your second question, you can't make all enums be strings, but you can make all occurrences of a given enum type to be strings, so you don't have to specify the custom type for each field individually:

```
enum SegmentType {
     option (scalapb.enum_options).type = "String";
     UNKNOWN = 0;
     TYPE_1 = 1;
     TYPE_2 = 2;
     TYPE_3 = 3;
}

message F {
  optional SegmentType segment_type = 1; // will be an Option[String]
}
```

Comment: That worked! would be nice if you add it to the ScalaPB documentation as well!

Comment: Great! Added a paragraph at the end of https://scalapb.github.io/customizations.html#custom-types